# Propel migration with multiple connections defined

Tags: symfony, propel

Is there any chance I can migrate only one database, if I have define multiple connections in my `config.yml`
If I run
`propel:migration:diff --connection=a` it still want to generate migration for all databases defined.
My vendors

> propel/propel-bundle                       1.2.7              Integration of Propel in Symfony2
>
> propel/propel1                             1.6.9              Propel is an open-source Object-Relational Mapping (ORM) for PHP5.

Comment: Was the below of help, @skowron?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Although I have Propel `1.7.1` I don't think this has changed since `1.6.9`.
You have to create a separate `buildtime-conf.xml` file for each connection and then pass the path to this file while calling `propel-gen diff`. So, let's say you have `a-buildtime-conf.xml`:

```
propel-gen . diff -Dpropel.buildtime.conf.file=a-buildtime-conf.xml
```

I found this by debugging the `GeneratorConfig::getBuildConnections()` method.

Comment: Hi @skowron-line .  It sounds like you a multiple master connections setup.  If I'm right, will please please share why you have/need this setup?


I'm just thinking that the ideal situation would be to have one maste with multiple slaves, so that you only have one entry point for data, and then your replication setup would take care of the rest

Comment: @Qiniso: I expect it is due to multiple environments, [like I discuss here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28375703/what-does-a-good-practice-propel-migrations-workflow-look-like), rather than multiple live database servers.